# Angular2 how to use replaceUrl:false in the app.routing.ts

Tags: angular2-routing

I defined a component for an error page, and would like to make it so the URL does not change any time I navigate to the error page. Can I use replaceUrl: false in the route definitions? If not how can I do this?

Edit:

I found this question that is exactly what I am looking for - the answer this links to looks interesting but I don't understand what NavigationError is, or what the code should look like that initiates this.
[Angular2 How to display error page while keeping route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075354/angular2-how-to-display-error-page-while-keeping-route#answer-44483648)

Seems like allowing replaceUrl:false in the route config would be simpler if possible.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the address to be changed in the browser? If you do, look at my answer here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261812/how-to-hide-route-id-and-params-in-angular2/46263086#46263086)

Comment: @DanR. Yes that's what I mean. But I don't want to have to specify the parameter in every place that I navigate to the error page. I was hoping to define the route as one that should not change the URL. Also, I won't have links as you show in your example, only navigation as a result of an error.